# How to compare years in a filter-controlled table by years

Tags: tableau-api, dashboard, tableau-desktop

sorry in advance if my question may be stupid, I created a table in desktop tableau where I compare three sizes, for longevity issues of the dashboard, this table is displayed with a filter that shows the years for the sizes under consideration. The analysis starts from 2015 until 2021 the measure I want to compare and the difference already calculated by LOD calculation of two measures represented in the tableau. What I would like is a new field in the table starting in 2016 that calculates for me the difference of (LOD calculation I already created) 2015 minus 2016. I attach an image to possibly clarify the discord the comparison measure I am interested in is the last 'delta'.

What I would like is a new field in the table starting in 2016 that calculates for me the difference of (LOD calculation I already created) 2015 minus 2016.